# Digit Pattern matching

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing

I have a list:

```
a = [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 7]
```

I would like to count how many times `2, 4` appear together

```
( 2 at index i and 4 at index i+1).
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you'd need to check every pair in your given list to see if the pair contains `2` and `4`. In Python, you can create pairs by using the `zip` built-in function.

In order to create adjacent pairs, we supply the list `a` as the first argument to `zip` and the *same list* one position forward:

```
list(zip(a, a[1:]))  # a[1:] is [2, 4, 5, 8, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 7]
```

This produces pairs of the form:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 4), (4, 5), (5, 8), (8, 2), (2, 4), ...]
```

Now, what we can do is *iterate through* these pairs (using `for`), unpack them to variables (`i` and `j`) and test our condition (one is equal to `2` and the other to `4`). This looks like this:

```
[i == 2 and j == 4 for i, j in zip(a, a[1:])]
```

This creates a list with `True/False` entries for pairs that succeed and fail the condition we set:

```
[False, True, False, False, False, True, False, True, False, False]
```

Here's where another built-in function comes in handy, `sum()`. You can supply `sum` with a list of values and it will sum these up to a single value; fortunately, in `Python`, `True` is treated as `1` so `sum` can easily sum it up and find a result if we supply the list we created previously:

```
sum(i == 2 and j == 4 for i,j in zip(a, a[1:]))
```

Doing this helps us reach the final result of `3`.

In a procedural way this can be translated as:

```
count = 0
for i,j in zip(a, a[1:]):
    if i == 2 and j == 4:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

This again yields `3` as does the `sum` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Join the list into a string and search for `'24'`.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 7]
>>> ''.join(map(str, a)).count('24')
3
```